Geth Private Network - Account management
I'm building a private blockchain using Geth. I created 2 accounts with command geth --datadir miner-node account new and geth --datadir rpc-node account new, then I added their address to genesis.json file in "alloc" field and I started my blockchain.
When I connect to my rpc node with the command geth attach http://localhost:8545 and I run eth.accounts I get one only account address from my console. What's the reason?
Presuming this blockchain will go in production, which is the safest way to manage my accounts? Are there some best practices?
Thank for helping <3
